# Get string between strings in c#

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to get string between same strings:

```
The texts starts here ** Get This String ** Some other text ongoing here.....
```

I am wondering how to get the string between stars. Should I should use some *regex* or other functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `Split`:

```
  string source = 
    "The texts starts here** Get This String **Some other text ongoing here.....";

  // 3: we need 3 chunks and we'll take the middle (1) one  
  string result = source.Split(new string[] { "**" }, 3, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

Comment: Did not know you could specify chunks! What's the benefit of explicitly specifying those?

Comment: @EpicKip: imagine, that you have, say, `10000` occurrencies of `**`. If you don't put `3`, you'll get an array with as many as `10001` items (which will be time and space consuming); if you do - just with `3`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `IndexOf` to do the same without regular expressions.
This one will return the first occurence of string between two "**" with trimed whitespaces. It also has checks of non-existence of a string which matches this condition.

```
public string FindTextBetween(string text, string left, string right)
{
    // TODO: Validate input arguments

    int beginIndex = text.IndexOf(left); // find occurence of left delimiter
    if (beginIndex == -1)
        return string.Empty; // or throw exception?

    beginIndex += left.Length;

    int endIndex = text.IndexOf(right, beginIndex); // find occurence of right delimiter
    if (endIndex == -1)
        return string.Empty; // or throw exception?

    return text.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex).Trim(); 
}    

string str = "The texts starts here ** Get This String ** Some other text ongoing here.....";
string result = FindTextBetween(str, "**", "**");
```

I usually prefer to not use regex whenever possible.

Comment: `"**".Length` instead of *magic number* `2` is a bit more accurate implementation

Comment: When wrapping logic into a *public* method, please, do not forget to *validate* its arguments (or at least, leave `//TODO: validate text, left, right here` comment). What if I call the routine as `var result FindTextBetween(null, null, null);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I have updated my answer :) Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use regex, [this could do](https://regex101.com/r/sk9Djc/1):

```
.*\*\*(.*)\*\*.*
```

The first and only capture has the text between stars.

Another option would be using `IndexOf` to find the position of the first star, check if the following character is a star too and then repeat that for the second set. `Substring` the part between those indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If you can have multiple pieces of text to find in one string, you can use following regex:

```
\*\*(.*?)\*\*
```

Sample code:

```
string data = "The texts starts here ** Get This String ** Some other text ongoing here..... ** Some more text to find** ...";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*\*(.*?)\*\*");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(data);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split` but this would only work if there is 1 occurrence of the word.

**Example:**

```
string output = "";
string input = "The texts starts here **Get This String **Some other text ongoing here..";
var splits = input.Split( new string[] { "**", "**" }, StringSplitOptions.None );
//Check if the index is available 
//if there are no '**' in the string the [1] index will fail
if ( splits.Length >= 2 )
    output = splits[1];

Console.Write( output );
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SubString for this:

```
String str="The texts starts here ** Get This String ** Some other text ongoing here";

s=s.SubString(s.IndexOf("**"+2));
s=s.SubString(0,s.IndexOf("**"));
```

Comment: There's a syntax error: `s.IndexOf("**"+2)` is wrong, correct is `s.IndexOf("**") + 2`